# Get-DSCConfiguration indicates consistency check or pull cmdlet is in progress for many days

Tags: dsc

I am not able to understand what exactly is happening under the cover but whenever I run get-dscconfiguration reports consistency check is in progress. I want to know what is happening for it to be in a wait state for many days??

```
PS C:\OnlyOnMyPC\azure-automation> Get-DscConfiguration
Get-DscConfiguration : Cannot invoke the Get-DscConfiguration cmdlet. The Consistency Check or Pull cmdlet is in progress and must
return before Get-DscConfiguration can be invoked. Use -Force option if that is available to cancel the current operation.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-DscConfiguration
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager:root/Microsoft/...gurationManager) [Get-DscConfigurat
   ion], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1,Get-DscConfiguration

PS C:\OnlyOnMyPC\azure-automation> Get-DscLocalConfigurationManager


ActionAfterReboot              : ContinueConfiguration
AgentId                        : BD46B63B-BD33-11E8-92D9-8CDCD4247D7F
AllowModuleOverWrite           : False
CertificateID                  :
ConfigurationDownloadManagers  : {}
ConfigurationID                :
ConfigurationMode              : ApplyOnly
ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins : 15
Credential                     :
DebugMode                      : {ForceModuleImport, ResourceScriptBreakAll}
DownloadManagerCustomData      :
DownloadManagerName            :
LCMCompatibleVersions          : {1.0, 2.0}
LCMState                       : Busy
LCMStateDetail                 : LCM is performing a consistency check.
LCMVersion                     : 2.0
StatusRetentionTimeInDays      : 10
SignatureValidationPolicy      : NONE
SignatureValidations           : {}
MaximumDownloadSizeMB          : 500
PartialConfigurations          :
RebootNodeIfNeeded             : False
RefreshFrequencyMins           : 30
RefreshMode                    : PUSH
ReportManagers                 : {}
ResourceModuleManagers         : {}
PSComputerName                 :
```

How to have this mystery resolved as soon as possble?

Thanks